# Binding to the 'create' event of jQuery UI widget outside the widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm having troubles binding to the 'create' event of the widget that uses jQuery UI Widget Factory. It only happens if I'm binding to it outside the widget. Please see the snippet (simplified for testing purposes)

```
(function($){

    $.widget('pr.test', {
        options: {
            create: function(e){
                // Shows up in the console
                console.log('Widget created');
            }
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

And then later in some other file I'm binding to this event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('body').test().on('testcreate', function(){
        // Doesn't show up in the console
        console.log('Widget created');
    });

});
```

I'm aware that I could just do this

```
$('body').test({
    create: function(){
        console.log('Widget created')
    }
});
```

but I need to be able to bind to the event multiple times after the widget initalization.
Can somebody please explain what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case somebody has the same problems. My mistake was calling the .on() method after the widget initialization, while I should have called it before. From my understanding the script was unaware of any event handlers bound to the 'create' event when it was fired.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pranacoder/59qy9/).

```
$.widget('pr.test', {
    options: {
        create: function(){
            console.log('Called from within the widget');
        }
    }
});

// Binding to the event before it is fired
$('body').on('testcreate', function(){
    console.log('Called from outside the widget');
});

$('body').test();

// Binding to the event after it is fired
$('body').on('testcreate', function(){
    console.log('This will not work');
});
```